# Pass variable as a parameter in \newgeometry

Tags: key-value

I have defined the following variable storing my margin settings:

```
\def \geometryTitlepage {
    left=25mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm
}
```

Then in the titlepage I want to set `\newgeometry`

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{
        \geometryTitlepage
    }
    \begin{center}
        *
        *
        *
    \end{center}
    \restoregeometry
\end{titlepage}
```

But the compiler throws an error:

```
!Package keyval Error: left=25mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm undefined.
```

When I put the values by hand everything is ok. But when I use variable it seems to add `undefined` at the end of the string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\expandafter\newgeometry\expandafter{\geometryTitlepage}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key-values are not expanded by default, so combining multiple keys into a single command requires expansion *first* before the separate keys can be interpreted. There are a number of ways of achieving this:

- `\expandafter\geometry\expandafter{\geometryTitlepage}`
- `\edef\x{\noexpand\geometry{\geometryTitlepage}}\x`

The latter option should be used inside a group to prevent `\x` (or whatever you choose) from "leaking" elsewhere (although not critical). This is already the case since you're using it inside the `titlepage` environment, thereby limiting its scope. For this reason, some use it also in this context

- `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\geometry{\geometryTitlepage}}\x`

which "destroys" `\x` after using it.

Comment: Whoa, thanks. I don't understand any of the code you provided, but it works.